# Read document from AngularFireStore

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

i'm so new in firebase, so i need some very basic help.

I have collection "Users" in firestore, whene i have documents with key (user id) and every document have some fields.

[image]

In my component i have variable `userData: Observable<any[]>`

After user login i want find his id in documents and get his info to userData variable.

```
  ...
  .then(user => {
    this.authState = user;

    // Here i want get user data and set it to my variable
    this.userData = this.afs.collection('Users').document(user.uid);


    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  })
```

But obviously, this is does not work. I will be gratfull for any help or tips with my question, thanks&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing all of this in the `.then` after the login Promise; map the `AngularFireAuth`'s `authState` observable in your `init`.

```
this.userData = this.afAuth.authState
  .switchMap { user => user ? this.afs.document("Users/${user.uid}").valueChanges() : of(null) }
```

So now that we have an Observable of the current user's data over time or null.